# C++ converting double to int in mathematical calculations

Tags: c++

When I write `cout<<3.0/2.0;`
I get 1.5
but when I write `cout<< 3.0*2.0;`
I get 6.
And if 3.0 and 2.0 are double values, shouldn't my result be a double value like 6.0?
According to what is the result  int or double?

Comment: More than one type can have the same output for a particular value.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: You can use `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << 3.0*2.0;` to get 6.0

Answer (score 9):

The result of `3.0 * 2.0` is very *much* a double<sup>(a)</sup>. However, the *presentation* of a value is not the value. You'll find that `6`, `6.0`, `6.00000`, `0.06E2`, `6000E-3` and even the symbolic `-6(epi×i)` are *all* the same value, with different presentations.

If you don't want the default presentation<sup>(b)</sup>, the `iostream` and `iomanip` headers have facilities to format numbers in *specific* formats, such as using this to get `6.0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    auto x = 3.0 * 2.0;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed << x << '\n';
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The usual arithmetic conversions specified in the standard come into play here (eg, `C++17 8 Expressions /11`):

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of scoped enumeration type, no conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same type, the expression is ill-formed.
> - If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted to long double.
> - **Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.**
> - *Other irrelevant stuff in the context of this question.*

---

<sup>(b)</sup> The actual rules for what gets printed by default are specified in the standard, but complex and locale-aware enough that it's probably easier for most people to just do explicit formatting :-)

Answer (score 4):

The rules for what the output data type is from a given arithmetic operation are well defined in C++. You can find it out at compile time by using [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

```
std::cout << typeid(3.0 * 2.0).name() << std::endl; // Prints 'd' for double instead of 'i' for integer
```

You might be surprised to find out that adding two values of one data type (char) can result in an output of a different data type:

```
std::cout << typeid('a'+'b').name() << std::endl; // Prints 'i' for integer instead of 'c' for character
```

In this case, you are explicitly stating that 2.0 and 3.0 are floating point types. The result is, unsurprisingly, also a floating point type. However, the cout utility is omitting the decimal point because the result is a whole number.

Comment: Keep in mind the *actual* strings are implementation-defined, they are not required to be `d` or `i`. That doesn't diminish your answer of course, just thought I'd raise the point. The `'a'+'b'` case is simply the integral promotions kicking in, where any integer type "less" than an `int` can become an `int`.